# ¿Cómo implementar cerrar sesión con Facebook, en react-native?

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, react-native, expo

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Expo utilizando react-native, implemente un Login con Facebook pero ahora quiero hacer Logout, no he encontrado en ningún lugar la forma de hacerlo

Este es el código que utilizo para el LogIn

```
async loginWithFacebook(){
    const { type, token } = await Expo.Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync('609042169609691', { permissions: ['public_profile', 'email'] })
    if(type=='success'){
      const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(token)
      firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential).catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error)
      })
    }
  }
```

Saludos
Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Ya pude resolver el problema, resulta que con firebase se maneja el uso de sesiones
Con este código se puede cerrar la sesión

```
async LogoutFacebook(){
    firebase.auth().signOut();
}
```